# Using jQuery in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This is the code from the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListView`.Here i am usisg labels to display the Item Name,Description etc etc from the database.

I want to use this http://valums.com/edit-in-place/ jQuery plugin to edit the columns.Can anyone please help me out with this??I mean how do i use this plugin to edit the fields and save them after editing to the database.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="background-color:#ffffff; color: #000000;"> 
        <div id="DFIP-Desc">          
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="style2" >
                <tr style="border:solid 1px #666666;">
                    <td style="border:solid 1px #666666; width:100px;">&nbsp;User</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="userIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userID") %>' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="border:solid 1px #666666;">
                    <td style="border:solid 1px #666666;">&nbsp;Item Name</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="itemNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itemName") %>' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="border:solid 1px #666666;">
                    <td style="border:solid 1px #666666; width:100px;">&nbsp;Offered Price</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="offeredPriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("offeredPrice") %>' /></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr style="border:solid 1px #666666;">
                    <td style="border:solid 1px #666666; width:150px;">&nbsp;Long Description</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="longDescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("longDescription") %>' Font-Size="14px" CssClass="align" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="border:solid 1px #666666;">
                    <td style="border:solid 1px #666666; width:100px;">&nbsp;Bargainable</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="bargainableLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("bargainable") %>' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="border:solid 1px #666666;">
                    <td style="border:solid 1px #666666; width:100px;">&nbsp;Condition</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="conditionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("condition") %>' />,(<asp:Label ID="ageYearsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ageYears") %>' /> Years,<asp:Label ID="ageMonthsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ageMonths") %>' /> Months)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="border:solid 1px #666666;">
                    <td style="border:solid 1px #666666; width:100px;">&nbsp;Warranty</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="warrantyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("warranty") %>' />,(<asp:Label ID="warrantyYearsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("warrantyYears") %>' /> Years,<asp:Label ID="warrantyMonthsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("warrantyMonths") %>' /> Months)</td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="itemIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itemID") %>' Visible="True" /></td> 
                </tr>       
            </table>     
         </div>        
    </td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i cant get thru with this part  
`//  bind an event listener that will be called when
 //  user saves changed content
 $('.editableText').change(function(){    
     var newValue = $(this).html();

     // do something         
     // For example, you could place an AJAX call here:  
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: "newfieldvalue=" + newValue,
        success: function(msg){
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
     });
 });`

Comment: Mistake 1: Use of `style` attribute. Mistake 2: `<table>` inside a `<td>`. Mistake 3: `runat="server"` on a `<td>`. Mistake 4: `"style2"` is a useless CSS class name.

Comment: @Monodeep what is that?  If its an answer post it in the box below.

Comment: how to bind an event listener that will be called when
user saves changed content

Comment: I'm confused, do you wan't to use jquery (client) or process the event on the server (runat=server)?

Comment: i wan to use jQuery to call a server side code to save the data to the databse...am i clear??or am i confusing you :(

Comment: When you say you "can't get thru this part" what do you mean exactly? Is that your code, or an example from the plugin site? Have you used JQuery before? AJAX?

Comment: its an example from the plugin site...i am very new to jQuery..actually i want the user to be able to edit the data as well as save it to the database using jQuery...is that possible??

Comment: It's definitely possible. You didn't answer the question about AJAX. You need to understand how to make client side requests as well to get this to work, and of course, how to process them on the server.

Comment: no i am not very familiar with AJAX or jQuery..could you please help me??
Please check this link[http://tricedeals.com/fleaMarket/dedicatedFleaItemPage.aspx?itemID=item1] ...just to get an idea of how the page looks..the white tabular format in the right to the blue patch is the part i want to edit and save.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is under the "usage" heading on the link you provided.

You mark a field as editable by finding it with jquery and running editableText(). Ex. put this in a script tag:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#longDescriptionLabel').editableText();
});
```

You then have to have a jquery function that catches the change and posts it back to your aspx page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 //  bind an event listener that will be called when
 //  user saves changed content
 $('#longDescriptionLabel').change(function(){    
     var newValue = $(this).html();

     // do something         
     // For example, you could place an AJAX call here:  
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "savelongDescriptionLabel.aspx",
        data: "longDescriptionLabel=" + newValue,
        success: function(msg){
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
     });
 });
```

Then in your savelongDescriptionLabel.aspx's page load you request["longDescriptionLabel"] and save it.

You will probably need to get the ID of the item you want to save though, and this you can do by using jquery: $(this).parent.find("#itemIDLabel").val(), then pas that value inside the data bit of the ajax call. 
    });

edit: used . for cssclass instead of # for ID in my jquery selector. 
edit2: Here is the reference for using ID selectors: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to hit the books. You admit you really don't understand AJAX or JQuery. You're in no position to ask users here to get your code working. SO users expect posters to put in a minimum of effort before they help. They get annoyed and downvote questions that expect them to do all the work.

Check out general articles for ASP.Net developers such as the following:

**http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx**

When you have done the research you will be in a position to ask tightly scoped questions that someone will be willing to answer. And more importantly, you will be in a position to actually evaluate what they are telling you.